# Looping through key values in object

Tags: javascript

Im getting an array of objects from localstorage:

```
saved_selection = window.localStorage.getItem('match_selection');

console.log('saved selection obj is ');
console.log(saved_selection);
```

The output is:

```
{"236":"Forward_2","243":"Forward_1"}
```

Now I want to loop through and get the key and value. So I do:

```
for(var index in saved_selection) {
    console.log(index + " -> " + saved_selection[index]); 
}
```

But I get:

```
0 -> { 
1 -> " 
2 -> 2 
3 -> 3
```

etc, instead of:

```
236 -> Forward_2
243 -> Forward_1
```

How do I achieve the desired output?

Comment: your loop iterates through the string. To make an object out of a string use JSON.parse()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to parse out the string returned by the localStorage:

```
saved_selection = JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem('match_selection') );
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that `{"236":"Forward_2","243":"Forward_1"}` is instance of **String**, not an **Object**.
for

```
var v1 = '{"236":"Forward_2","243":"Forward_1"}';
```

this will not works, but for

```
var v2 = {"236":"Forward_2","243":"Forward_1"};
```

You should convert `String` to `Object` with **JSON.parse** method.

```
saved_selection = JSON.parse(saved_selection);
for(var index in saved_selection) {
    console.log(index + " -> " + saved_selection[index]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You, my friend are trying to get the index of a complete stringized object. It does not work that way. First you have to parse it and break it down to individual components using `JSON.parse()`.

Look below :

**JS:**

```
var saved_selection = JSON.parse('{"236":"Forward_2","243":"Forward_1"}') ;

var saved_selection1 = '{"236":"Forward_2","243":"Forward_1"}' ;

for(var index in saved_selection) {
    console.log(index + " -> " + saved_selection[index]); 
}
for(var index in saved_selection1) {
    console.log(index + " -> " + saved_selection1[index]); 
}
```

The first for loop returns the desired O/P but the second one does not.

Find the working fiddle here :http://jsfiddle.net/eMVNk/2/